# How to show this function is analytic under these condition?(Please check my proof)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \vert \vert z \vert <2  \}  \to \mathbb{C}$. And there are finite roots of the $f$ in $D$

Say $g(z) = (f(z))^4$, $h(z) = (f(z))^7$ and these functions are analytic on $D$

Prove $f \in H(D)$ [I.e. analytic on $D$]

---

Since roots are finite, $f(z) = (z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n) k(z)$ for a set of the roots, $\{ z_1, z_2,.. , 
z_n \}$ (Here $k(z) \neq 0$, $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$)

Since $g(z),h(z) \in H(D) $, there are no singularity points of the $(k(z))^4$ and $(k(z))^7$ in $D$

Hence, we can conclude $(k(z))^4, (k(z))^7 \in H(D)$

With the same reason, $k(z) \in H(D)$

Hence $f(z) \in H(D)$

I don't have any confidence my proof is right or not. If there are any mistakes, please pinpoint my idea and proof. Also more easier the other ways always appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "With the same reason, $k(z)\in H(D)$".  What reason is that? I don't see anything in the previous discussion remotely like this.

Comment: the factorization $f(z) = (z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n) k(z)$ is not particularly true unless $f$ is analytic(meromorphic); for example think of $f(z)= e^{\frac{-1}{|z|^2}}, z \ne0, f(0)=0$ while if one is given that the roots have "finite multiplicity' (whatever that means as again that is not a well defined concept outside of the analytic/meromorphic realm) you still can have trouble as $f(z)=\sqrt |z|$ shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that unless one is in the meromorphic realm, the notion of finite multiplicity zero is quite tricky (could be sometimes defined for say continuos complex functions using the continuos degree) and without it one can easily give counterexamples like $f(z)=e^{-\frac {1}{|z|^2}}, z \ne 0, f(0)=0$ that are infinitely differentiable as real two-variable functions (all partial derivatives exist etc), but for which there is no factorization as claimed by the OP.

So one has to use the hypothesis directly and note that $g,h$ have the same zero set as $f$, hence being analytic, their zeroes are isolated and of finite multiplicity, hence $f(z)=\frac{g(z)^2}{h(z)}$ is meromorphic on $D$. But obviously $f$ cannot have poles as $g,h$ would still have them, so $f$ analytic. Done!